# Can I book a passport appointment in India for re-issue (after minor change) at a PSK or POPSK other than the one in my home city?

Tags: passports, passport-renewals, f1-visas

I have a correction in my parent's surname in my current passport and want to make in consistent with my other documents (as I will apply for an F-1 visa for this Fall). I will be staying at my relatives' outside my home-city (which has a PSK and does not have an appointment date for my stay in home-city) and want to apply for this change at the earliest, so at the POPSK at my relatives' town (which has appointment dates during my stay there).

Will they issue this change?

Answer (score 1):

[The Passport Rules, 1980](https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/pdf/Passport_Rules_1980.pdf) state :

> (2) An officer referred to in column (2) of Schedule 1 shall, for the purpose
> of issue of a passport or travel document, exercise jurisdiction in respect of applications for such issue made by persons ordinarily residing in the territories specified in the corresponding entries in column 3 of the said Schedule: .[Provided that in exceptional and urgent cases the said officer may entertain an application for the issue of a passport or travel document from a person not ordinarily residing within his jurisdiction and may issue a passport or travel document to such a person for a period not exceeding twenty-four months.]

Since :

> Passport Seva Kendras and Post Office Passport Seva Kendras are extended arms of Passport Offices and render front-end services related to passport issuance.

The PSK/POPSK you are applying to must be a branch of a Passport Office that has jurisdiction over where you live normally, but it can be anyone of them

You can find the relevant offices [here](https://passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/locatePSK/locatePFCInp)